# Post to my Facebook page (not user status )

Tags: vb.net, facebook, post

I have now spend the weekend trying to figure out how to post a status update to a facebook page (not user ) with out any luck (Yes my wife is angry Wink | ;-) .

Looks like on the net there is no working example. 
This is what I got so far is:

```
Dim fb = New FacebookClient()
fb.AppSecret = app_secret
fb.AppId = app_id
Dim result = fb.[Get]("oauth/access_token", New With {Key .client_id = app_id, Key .client_secret = app_secret, Key .grant_type = scope, Key .redirect_uri = Url})
fb.AccessToken = result.access_token
fb.Post("/me/feed", New With {Key .message = "My first post"})
```

But still no luck , anybody how can point me in the right direction , and please also include info how to get the access token.

Ps. Im using the facebook-csharp-sdk

Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this document right here: "https://developers.facebook.com/docs/wordpress/" which explains the Wordpress plugin and how to use your app to post to your own Facebook page (this is very similar to your case). Hope this helps!